# Working around loss of support for type constraint being self

Tags: typescript

This is something I've been doing in older versions of TypeScript and I use this method in C#, but it doesn't work in the latest 1.0 version of TypeScript.

Here's what worked in the past:

```
class Base<T extends Base<T>> {
    public children : Array<T>;

    doAction() {
        this.children[0].promise(); // used to work
    }

    promise() : T {
        return this; // used to work
    }
}

class Child extends Base<Child> {
    public myString: string;
}

new Child().promise().myString; // used to work
```

Everything used to work in harmony.

Now in the TypeScript 1.0 I get this error on the `Base<T extends Base<T>>` definition:

> Constraint of a type parameter cannot reference any type parameter from the same type parameter list.

How can I fix this example class to work without requiring any casts outside of the classes or casting anything to "any"? Maybe this pattern should be changed?

Comment: Note that this pattern will no longer be necessary when TypeScript supports a [polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) in TS1.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are no longer allowed to use `T` here:

```
class Base<T extends Base<T>>
--------------------------^
```

You either have to make your class non-generic or use:

```
class Base<T extends Base<any>>
```

The reason given for this was to make the compiler simpler:

> In our continued efforts to simplify the language, we're simplifying what generic constraints can entail.
>
> The added overhead in terms of type-checking, error-reporting, and design complexity did not add enough additional expressiveness to make it worthwhile for 1.0. We may revisit this in future versions of TypeScript.

-- [Breaking Changes Wiki](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Thanks. It's not as nice, but I was able to make things work by doing `Base<T extends Base<any>>`. I had to do a cast to any, but that's not a big deal within the base class: http://goo.gl/8JSLxq

Answer (score 6):

I accepted Steve's answer because he suggested to use `Base<T extends Base<any>>`, but I wanted to keep a copy of the code change that fixed the problem on Stack Overflow:

```
class Base<T extends Base<any>> { // 1. Set as any
    children: Array<T>;

    doAction() {
        this.children[0].promise();
    }

    promise(): T {
        return <any> this; // 2. cast to any
    }
}

class Child extends Base<Child> {
    public myString: string;
}

new Child().promise().myString;
```

This requires a cast to any, but it's not so bad since it's only in the base class. This change doesn't affect anything using the Child or Base classes, so overall it was a very ideal alternative.

---

**Update**: In TS 1.7+ this can be done using a [polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910):

```
class Base {
    children: Array<this>;

    doAction() {
        this.children[0].promise();
    }

    promise(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public myString: string;
}

new Child().promise().myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

`promise() : T { return this; }` it is very weak assumption that can be easily broken, because  downcasting defined in a base class just cannot work for any sub-class

For example in you case, if anyone defines `class SuperChild extends Child {}` then `promise()` of `SuperChild` is going to give you `Child` instead of `SuperChild`.

Besides that here is how you can make it work the way it used to:

```
class Base<T> {
    public children : Array<T>;

    constructor(
        private toSelf: () => T,
        private toBase: (something: T) => Base<T>
    ) {
    }


    doAction() {
        this.toBase(this.children[0]).promise(); // used to work
    }

    promise() : T {
        return this.toSelf(); // 
    }
}

class Child extends Base<Child> {
    public myString: string;
}

function toThis() { return this; }

new Child(toThis, x => x).promise().myString; // used to work
```