# Method chaining when extending TypeScript classes

Tags: typescript, definition, extends

Is there an easy way to change the return type of a method when extending a class without having to explicitly set it in each new definition? I'd like to simplify my definitions that look like this...

```
declare class Foo {
    add(): Foo;
}

declare class Bar extends Foo {
    add(): Bar;
    remove(): Bar;
}

declare class Baz extends Bar {
    add(): Baz;
    remove(): Baz;
    destroy(): Baz;
}

// Usage...
var foo = new Foo().add();    
var bar = new Bar().add().remove();    
var baz = new Baz().add().remove().destroy();
```

Comment: It's not ideal, but this is the way I do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024723/188246 -- Maybe there's a better way that someone knows though?

Comment: I could get it working for the `Bar` class, but not the `Baz` class.

Comment: oh yeah, it doesn't work for more than one layer of inheritance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by the type system yet. [See issue #285 in GitHub for tracking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/285).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by modifying David's example a little bit. It's not ideal, but it works.

```
declare class IFoo<T> {
    add(): T;
}

declare class IBar<T> extends IFoo<T> {
    remove(): T;
}

declare class IBaz<T> extends IBar<T> {
    destroy(): T;
}

declare class Foo extends IFoo<Foo> { }
declare class Bar extends IBar<Bar> { }
declare class Baz extends IBaz<Baz> { }

// Okay
var foo = new Foo().add();
var bar = new Bar().add().remove();
var baz = new Baz().add().remove().destroy();
```

[Working example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20class%20IFoo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20IBar%3CT%3E%20extends%20IFoo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20remove()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20IBaz%3CT%3E%20extends%20IBar%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20destroy()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20Foo%20extends%20IFoo%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0Adeclare%20class%20Bar%20extends%20IBar%3CBar%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0Adeclare%20class%20Baz%20extends%20IBaz%3CBaz%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Okay%0Avar%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo().add()%3B%0Avar%20bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar().add().remove()%3B%0Avar%20baz%20%3D%20new%20Baz().add().remove().destroy()%3B%0A)