# Typescript: error on A<T extends B<T>>

Tags: generics, typescript

How to overcome this error when extending generic class `A<T extend B<T>>`? The idea is to add some properties to B while still keeping it generic.

Intended use is genric version of this:

```
interface IEmployee extends ng.resource.IResource<IEmployee>
{
    id: number;
    firstName : string;
    lastName : string;
}
interface IEmployeeResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEmployee>
{
    update() : IEmployee;
}
```

This is ***non-generic*** solution. I would like to make a generic solution but I get error **Constraint of a type parameter cannot reference any type parameter from the same type parameter list.**

From what I understand (from c++) one should be able to do this:

```
/// make all resource models have an id.
interface MyResourceModel<T> extends ng.resource.IResource<T> {
    id: number;
}

/// make all resources have an update action.
interface MyResourceClass<T extends MyResourceModel<T>> extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<T>
{
    update() : T;
}
```

How does TypeScript solve this? Is there any *(not so ugly)* workaround to this limitation?

Thank you.

**Edit**: there is already a simmilar question with a solution/workaround ([Working around loss of support for type constraint being self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003188/working-around-loss-of-support-for-type-constraint-being-self)). Applying this solution to my problem I would get

```
interface MyResourceClass<T extends MyResourceModel<any>> extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<T> { 
                                                     ^--- note the 'any'
    update(): T;
}
```

This was the solution at the time, but now things changed a bit and TypeScript 1.7 and later should (supposedly) support this functionality. I have triend version 1.7.x-dev and 1.8.x-dev but compiler still complains with above error.

How can this be done using latest version of typescript? Since this is (supposedly) supported I would prefer a proper solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out [polymorphic 'this' type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910). It's coming in TypeScript 1.7.

Comment: I'm running TypeScript 1.8.0-dev (nightly) - also tried last 1.7.0-dev.20151016 and still cant get it to compile without errors. Is this something yet to come or should be working in 1.7.x and 1.8.x and needs different implementation to achieve above results.